# Code Igniter Session issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Codeigniter session will not unset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7866332/codeigniter-session-will-not-unset)

I am using codeignitor. My code seems to be good.But the problem is sometimes $this->session->unset_userdata('user'); seems to work and sometimes dont.

here is my controller function

> ```
> function logout()
>   {
>
>           $this->session->unset_userdata('user');
>           //I have also tried $this->session->sess_destroy();
>           redirect('home','refresh');
>   }
> ```

Comment: I think you should use $this->session->sess_destroy() since it's a logout function. What do you mean by "sometimes dont"? You still can visit the secure pages?

Comment: Are you getting errors? Make sure you have `error_reporting()` set to a development level and `display_errors` on.

Comment: thanx but I had tried it.... but finally when I used $this-.session->set_userdata('user',NULL); instead of destroying it worked for me...

Comment: Can you take a look at your cookie and determine if the data is set in there or not?  This will help you debug